# How to run script in specific directory in tmux?

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

I'm trying to execute a script that is in my path to run my application. It should run two java backends (don't ask) and have one window where I will run the front-end after java finished booting.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

tmux new-session -d "./backend/spring/run '$1'"
tmux split-window -v "./backend/grails/run '$1'"
tmux split-window -v
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

But got an error:

```
server exited unexpectedly
no server running on /tmp/tmux-85609/default
no sessions
```

I've also tried using an absolute path. Got the same error.

Is there a way to execute a shell script in a specific path?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that somehow the first `split-window` causes the death of the tmux server. I wonder if what you run with it even matters at all.

Comment: @TomYan the code was taken from stack overflow with python and vim and it works fine. Only when I try to run a script from the path, it gives this error. I will try to simple shell script to see if it works.